# Multiple ADODB.Connection in vbScript

Tags: vbscript, connection, ado

I have an array of database servers, and want to execute the same query for all of them in a loop.
But after the first iteration the I get following error :
- Error Number: `3704`
- Description: `Operation is not allowed when the object is closed`

The code that I've implemented is:

```
     Dim username
     Dim password
     Dim serverList(4)
     serverList(0) = "ServerAddress0"
     serverList(1) = "ServerAddress1"
     serverList(2) = "ServerAddress2"
     serverList(3) = "ServerAddress3"

     'username and password are properly set
     for counter = 0 to UBound(serverList)-1
       Set connObj = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
       Set rsObj = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
       connString = ..........
       connObj.Open connString, username, password
       'ERROR comes here, in second iteration.

       sqlScript = "SELECT * FROM ......"
       rsObj.open sqlScript, connObj

       Do While Not rsObj.EOF
          'record set is fetched.....
          rsObj.MoveNext
       Loop

       'current connection is closed
       rsObj.close
       connObj.close

     Next
```

**Note:** For the first iteration this code works perfectly. Error come for second iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution for this issue:
While iterating over the servers, I was also trying to close connection object for each connection.

```
   ......
   rsObj.close
   connObj.close

Next 'end of iteration over servers.
```

Now I moved the close statements out of the loop. *i.e.* while iterating let the objects be open.

```
   ......
Next 'end of iteration over servers.

rsObj.close
connObj.close
```

So, it was all related to the open/close state of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

(0) Disable "On Error Resume Next" (if you use it)

(1) As UBound() returns the last index, not the size, change

```
for counter = 0 to UBound(serverList)-1
```

to

```
for counter = 0 to UBound(serverList)
```

(2) As it's possible that you messed up the connection string, publish real code for

```
connString = ..........
```

(3) As VBScript has `Until` change

```
Do While Not rsObj.EOF
```

to

```
Do Until rsObj.EOF
```

(4) As your recordset is named `rsObj` change

```
rsNice.MoveNext
```

to

```
rsObj.MoveNext
```

If you did construct the connection string properly, (4) is the cause of the error.

Comment: (2) is not an issue, coz I'm getting proper results for first iteration.
(1) is also not an issue, coz at least it must have iterated for 3 servers
sry for point (4) was a typo.